# Url Path Alias is not working with the "raw value from URL contextual filter"

Tags: views

I could really use some help with this one. Long story short, I have a contextual filter which pulls the taxonomy term from the url (2nd position).

For example: if I'm at walldamp/drupal/acoustics, it will pull all the nodes with the tag "acoustics".

Here's the problem: Drupal doesn't read path alias's. The actual address for walldamp/drupal/acoustics, is something like walldamp/node/59. So if I have an article tagged 59, it works.

I do not want to change all my tag's to the node number, because this needs to be really user friendly. How can I get my contextual filter to read the url displayed, or is there another work around?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

How have your configured your contextual filter? I have the following configuration and it's working fine for me:

1. ***Contextual filters***: Has taxonomy term ID
   You also need to specify `validation criteria` for this filter, my setting is:

   a) Specify validation criteria = Taxonomy Term
   b) Select the correct vocabulary.
   c) Set `Filter value type` to `Term name converted to term ID`
2. ***Create a relationshiop*** of `Content: Taxonomy terms on node`

   a) Select the correct vocabulary.
   b) Set `Require this relationship` to true

You may also wan't to use `Has taxonomy term ID width depth` if you have nested terms in your vocabulary.